# SharePoint document library Multi User field set only odd position users in case of Office documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I am trying to set users in Multi-User field of document library documents by using CSOM. It works properly for normal documents(non-office docs) but for office documents it is setting only odd position users in Multi-User field.

e.g. if I want to set "User1;User2;User3" then after execution, for office documents I am getting "User1;User3".  Here "User2" is missing.  For non-office documents it works properly.

Does anyone have any clue on this front?

Comment: can you provide source code, i have tested in my environment and it works properly for both of type office and non-office documents